# How can I emulate this wheel from the mowing unit of a ride-on mower?

Tags: building, design, moc

I am trying to build a model of a specific ride-on mower with Lego and I cannot find a satisfying solution for the wheels supporting the mowing unit.

This is what they look like on the original:

[image: The part I want to model]

[image: Another angle]

Note that the bottom of the wheel is below the bottom line of the unit that it supports.

The scale on which I am working and my best solution so far is this (the front part):

[image: My attempt]

[image: Another angle]

The wheel nicely extends below the structure it supports, but:

- horizontally, it extends rather far from the structure,
- it builds up quite high vertically,
- the construction is not very robust.

Thus my question is: What other part or combination of parts could I use to emulate this wheel? I prefer if the required parts are easily available in red, but I appreciate other suggestions as well, as I may have missed something that I can do with the parts at hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first thought would be to try and build this using 2x [32017 - Technic Liftarm 5 Thin](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32017#T=C&C=5) and [the following combination of a 1/2 bush and a tire](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4265cc01#T=C) (same tire you have on the wheel on the black part of your build, though the front tire might fit too).

[image][image]

If you use a 2L axle (in red!) this should look quite sleek. Not sure if the tire is going to be tall enough to support the mower, but it would definitely be sturdy, given that you're using Technic.